# Mysql show Name, SUM(Amount) WHERE Amount is less than 210 AND SUM(Amount) is greater or equal to 210

Tags: mysql

Mysql table

```
Name   | Amount
------------
name1  | 150
name1  | 90
name2  | 100
name2  | 110
name3  | 10
```

In result need something like

```
Name   | SUM(Amount)
------------
name1  | 240
name2  | 210
```

Tried

```
 SELECT Name, SUM(Amount)
 WHERE Amount < 210 AND SUM(Amount) >= 210
 GROUP BY Name
```

But get error `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function`

If I remove `AND SUM(Amount) >= 210` code works

Tried to think... do I need as if at first get `SUM(Amount) AS SumAmount` and in the same query instead of `AND SUM(Amount) >= 210` use `AND SumAmount >= 210`? ... but two `SELECT` in one query...

Something like ?

```
 SELECT SUM(Amount) AS SumAmount
 WHERE Amount < 210
 GROUP BY Name

 SELECT Name, SUM(Amount)
 WHERE SumAmount >= 210
 GROUP BY Name
```

Please, advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `HAVING` clause to filter up aggregated results like `SUM()`, etc.

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Amount)
FROM   tableName
WHERE  Amount < 210
GROUP  BY Name
HAVING SUM(Amount) >= 210
```

Comment: The answer is correct, but not the explanation:  `HAVING` does not evaluate aggregate functions; it is a filter applied after grouping to the resultset column.  It is equivalent to an enclosing `select * from ( your-query-here ) where predicate-from-having-clause`

Comment: The solution works. As I understand at first get all `WHERE  Amount < 210` and then show only those where `SUM(Amount) >= 210`. It is ok for me. Is there any problems? Sorry, can not understand (how to use) `where predicate-from-having-clause`